# How to work with entities related to the User and implement their APIs

Tags: spring-boot, rest, entity-framework

For security reasons, I learned that the less sensitive data you share with the client, the better. For example, when the user logs into the website, the backend doesn't send back all of its informations, but just as much as it's needed. Now, the problem is: how can I implement apis for entities related to the user, since the data shared on the client is not the "real" User?

For example, take a look at this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
public class ChatMessage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Chat chat;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String content;

    private boolean seen=false;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime sentAt;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User sender;
}
```

This one has been associated to a controller method for persistance. As I said earlier, this class is related to the User, but the client doesn't have access to the actual User class, but just some of its properties represented by the JWTAuthResponse class. This mean I can't create the proper ChatMessage object on the client to send to the backend. A solution could be to create a DTO class just for the controller, and then getting the user from the database by its username, and after that instantiating the ChatMessage object. But that sounds pretty tedious to me, especially if a project has a lot of entities related to the User, you would have to do this kind of conversion everytime. Is there a solution for this?

## This is my User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") })
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

## And this is the data I send back to the client when the user logs in:

```
public class JWTAuthResponse {
    private String username;
    private String accessToken;
    private String tokenType = "Bearer";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking DTOs are the best option everytime your entity model doesn't match the data you send to the client. There are some libraries that help you convert your entity to DTO and vice-versa, like [this one](https://modelmapper.org/). Good practise is to keep DTOs on the controllers layer and covert them to entities before passing to the business logic.

If you don't want to use DTOs and just avoid one field to be serialized you should consider `@JsonIgnore`. This annotation tells the serializer Jackson to ignore the field you are annotating, so it won't appear in the JSON you are sending to the client.

Keep in mind that what you are doing is a security risk, if you have sensible informations that you don't want to pass to the client, separate them from the entities you use in the business logic.
It goes without saying not to store passwords on the DB but I don't think that is production code.